# How to extract the host name from a git repo URI?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Given a git repository URI Like

```
git@company-name.com:/company-name/repo.git
```

or

```
https://company-name.com/company-name/repo.git
```

How can I extract `company-name.com` from them? I am trying to fetch the hostname so I can pass them to a cookbook called `ssk_known_hosts`.

Comment: You say you want to extract the host name from a URI, but the first one is not a valid URI (It is missing the scheme). What do you want as a result for invalid URIs? Reject them?

Comment: I think first one can be called a URI other than URL. And yes I would like to reject them.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, I just checked the Git docs, it says first example uses  SSH transfer protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Regular Expression to extract the hostname from the url ([regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mt5xa8/3)). This expression will match any user and both protocols (http/https).

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@(.+?):|https?:\/\/(.+?)\/
```

Usage:

```
repo_uri = '...'
repo_host = repo_uri.scan( /[a-zA-Z0-9_]+@(.+?):|https?:\/\/(.+?)\//).last.first
```

Comment: Awesome I will add ruby context to your answer. To make it complete

Comment: `(.*)@(.+?):|http(s?)?:\/\/(.+?)\/` will this match any user in place for `git` and both `http` and `https`?

Comment: @Starx: "will this match...?" -  use the regex101 for this kind of questions. it's very useful!

Comment: @Starx click on the link to check for yourself

Answer (score 1):

Use the proper tools for this. URI parsing is a solved problem.

```
require 'uri'

s = 'https://company-name.com/company-name/repo.git'
uri = URI(s)
uri.host # => "company-name.com"
```

Comment: The URI method works for the OP's second example but is confused by the first.

Comment: @moveson: well, he said he can use either, so... :)

Comment: I read his post as requiring a parser that could handle both formats ("How can I extract `company-name.com` from *them*?"). If the OP can live with just the URI format, then I agree yours is the correct answer.

Comment: Fair enough. haha. But I was asking for a solution applicable for both cases. The `or` used to identify possibilities.

Comment: @moveson: but one can simply preprocess the string with `s.gsub('git@', 'https://')`, and now we can use this `URI` approach for both. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Agreed, but at that point, the custom regex solution proposed in the other answer begins to look a bit simpler, at least to my (relatively untrained) eye.

Comment: Indeed, what a simple approach. But in both solutions if 'git` is not the user then the list keeps on increasing.

Comment: @moveson simpler in terms of cyclomatic complexity - yes. More clear/easier to grasp - hell no (IMHO, obviously). Regular expressions is a powerful gun with a powerful problem: one simply can't reliably tell at a glance, wtf is it what this [abstract] regex is doing. You've heard the saying, "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems.", right? :) Or maybe it's just me who can't read regexes :)

Comment: @moveson: No, `URI` is not confused by the first. It is correctly rejecting it as invalid. The problem is that the OP says he wants to extract information from a "repository URI", but then posts an example that is not a URI. It is not clear from the question what the OP wants to happen with something which is not a URI. So, rejecting it is well within the OP's specification.